# creating google chart from csv using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, jquery-csv

Here is my code to create google chart from csv data. code look fine but still there is some error.

Code looks fine but error is may be due to some jquery syntext. I appreciate if someone can help me

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
       // grab the CSV
       $.get("Chart1-data.csv", function(csvString) {
          // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        alert(arrayData);
          // this new DataTable object holds all the data
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

          // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
          view.setColumns([0,1]);

         // set chart options
         var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
         };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chart1-data.csv

```
Category,

A,34

B,23

C,14

D,57

E,18    

Other,5
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

i.e. line where script ends

UPDATE: there was `});` missing. Now no error but chart does not appear

Comment: Since your question was how to fix your error, you might want to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Andy: I appreciate your help dude. but I wanted to create google chart from csv, as I titled. If I mark this as answered then I could not post same quesion otherwise it would be marked as duplicate

Comment: Set breakpoints in your code so you can see that it's doing what it's meant to be doing. Are you targeting the right element for example? Is anything being assigned to `data`? Does `view` look right when you've assigned a visualisation to it? A couple of things I would check.

Comment: Yes this things are fine. I followed this doc which works successfully there : http://economistry.com/2013/07/easy-data-visualization-with-google-charts-and-a-csv/

Comment: What does `arrayData` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing brackets for `$.get(` should be `});` not just `}`;

```
$.get({
 // code
});
```

And you're also missing a closing curly bracket to close your function.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayMEg/)

Comment: thanks, but now there's no error. Though it does not show chart

Comment: Not upvote. You can click on the tick to say that an answer has been successfully answered.