# Using google charts and csv-file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Charts to display some data from a csv file.

I've looked on stack overflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503008/creating-google-chart-from-csv-using-js-jquery),
and I tried following this tutorial ([here](http://economistry.com/2013/07/easy-data-visualization-with-google-charts-and-a-csv/#comment-139)) but I can't seem to get past the first step, accessing the csv file.

I download the `jquery.cvs-0.71.js` and placed it together with my cvs and html-file in the same folder. I use the cvs file from the tutorial.

This is my code for the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Chart Example</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
<script>
  // wait till the DOM is loaded
  $(function() {
     // grab the CSV
     $.get("kzn1993.csv", function(csvString) {
        // display the contents of the CSV
        $("#chart").html(csvString);
     });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really have no idea why it's not working. I try to open the `.html` file, but the page remains blank. The title is set though.

Any help?
Thanks!

Error log in javascript console:

> Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///../../kzn1993.csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Do you have any message in console log?

Comment: Yes! I edited them in the original post

Comment: Okay, I see what went wrong here. I used local resources from my filesystem. So now I put them on my webserver, and the errors are gone, but I don't see any results.

Comment: I you break on line `$("#chart").html(csvString);` what is the value `csvString`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I'm afraid. Can you explain a little more detailed how that's done? I'm using eclipse, and when I open my html page with the build in eclipse browser, it does show the content of my csv file.

Comment: Open your page in a browser (the one hosted on your webserver), find the script in the browser's development tools (F12 in most browsers, then Scripts/Sources tab), then click on the line number containing that line. When you refresh the page it will break on and you will be able to inspect the value of the variable.

Comment: I followed your steps and I think this is the value (although it seems rather odd): csvString: "
↵<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
↵
↵</head>

Comment: That's not my csv file, but my css file. However, I have no idea how i t got data from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem with the same example. Finally I got it run. The reason is due to run the server with eclipse launcher.
If you place the csv file in the wtpwebapps/yourapp directory and refresh several times the html page it will run.
In my case I found the directory on:
C:\Users\MYUSER\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\MYRAPP